# How can I hydrate the Modx store using the Next js 13 APP catalog >=

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, mobx, hydration

I can't find a way to transfer to the context store because Mobx-react-lite requires hooks

./book-store.ts

```js
// we need to enable static rendering for prevent rerender on server side and leaking memory
import { enableStaticRendering } from "mobx-react-lite";
import { BooksStore, type Book } from "./model"

// enable static rendering ONLY on server
enableStaticRendering(typeof window === "undefined")

// init a client store that we will send to client (one store for client)
let clientStore: BooksStore

const initStore = (initData:Book[]) => {
// check if we already declare store (client Store), otherwise create one
  const store = clientStore ?? new BooksStore();
// hydrate to store if receive initial data
  if (initData) store.hydrate(initData)

// Create a store on every server request
  if (typeof window === "undefined") return store
// Otherwise it's client, remember this store and return 
if (!clientStore) clientStore = store;
  return store
}

// Hoook for using store
export function useStore(initData: Book[]) {
  return initStore(initData)
}
```

./app/template.ts
I want to wrap the root element with a provider.

```js
import { useStore } from "@/src/entities/book-store"
import { Store } from "@/src/entities/book-store/ui"
import { Book } from "@/src/entities/book-store/model"
import axios from "axios"
import { use } from "react"


export default function Template({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const data = use(axios({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
  }).then(data => data.data)) as Book[]    
  const store = useStore(data)
  return <Store.Provider value={store} >{children}</Store.Provider>
}
```

`mobx-react-lite requires React with Hooks support`

How can the store be hydrated in a different way or what is wrong here